# Combining the results of two queries with identical columns into a single result set

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I could use some guru help returning this data in one call....

```
SELECT TOP 10 tblData.*, (
    SELECT  TOP 10 tblData.*
    FROM    tblData
    WHERE   pk >= 5481 AND dev_ID = 'REC1' AND code_ID = 'FMU' AND
                        CAST(event_date_time as DATE) = '10/18/2013'
    ORDER BY pk ASC
    )
FROM    tblData
WHERE   pk <= 5481 AND dev_ID = 'REC1' AND code_ID = 'FMU' AND 
        CAST(event_date_time as DATE) = '10/18/2013'
ORDER BY pk DESC
```

Comment: Did you try using a union?

Comment: No little sketchy on that could use some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally produced a working solution, posting here for anyone else that may come across this....

```
Select * From
(SELECT TOP 10 tblData.*
FROM    tblData
WHERE   pk <= 5481 AND dev_ID = 'REC1' AND code_ID = 'FMU' AND
    CAST(event_date_time as DATE) = '10/18/2013'
UNION
SELECT  TOP 10 tblData.*
FROM    tblData
WHERE   pk >= 5481 AND dev_ID = 'REC1' AND code_ID = 'FMU' AND
    CAST(event_date_time as DATE) = '10/18/2013') A
ORDER BY pk ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try using UNION or UNION ALL

UNION, Specifies that multiple result sets are to be combined and returned as a single result set.

ALL, Incorporates all rows into the results. This includes duplicates. If not specified, duplicate rows are removed.

```
(SELECT TOP 10 tblData.*
FROM    tblData
WHERE   pk <= 5481 AND dev_ID = 'REC1' AND code_ID = 'FMU' AND 
        CAST(event_date_time as DATE) = '10/18/2013'
ORDER BY pk DESC)
UNION 
(SELECT  TOP 10 tblData.*
FROM    tblData
WHERE   pk >= 5481 AND dev_ID = 'REC1' AND code_ID = 'FMU' AND
        CAST(event_date_time as DATE) = '10/18/2013'
ORDER BY pk ASC)
```

Comment: On my first try the UNION got lost somewhere in the text editor. Did you try with the sql that shows now?

Comment: syntax error on UNION, I have tried UNION and can not seem to get the code correct

Comment: Try with brackets. I'm used to MySQL and never used SQL SERVER 2008. Please if you get any errors, copy them exactly.